# Navigation between three equally important tools

Tags: android, navigation

I am developing an app that will consist of three tools, each equally important. However, I am having trouble deciding what is the best way to implement navigation between them. My initial instinct was to use tabs, but after looking into this, I am hesitant to use them for two reasons:

1. Tabs are usually used for different material of the same type, like different genres of music, or different sections in a newspaper. The sections of my app are used to achieve the same goal, but they're completely different in structure and content, so it will be like switching between three unrelated screens. That means I will have to put different stuff in the action bar for each activity, which I don't think you're supposed to do with tabs.
2. tabs force you to use fragments, but I've already developed some of the tools as activities.They definitely feel like they're meant to be solid activities and not just fragments, so I would rather keep them that way.

Should I go ahead and use tabs anyway, or what else should I use instead?

Comment: A sugestion is to use fragments  with navigation drower, because if is like you said tabs is not the best way, but navigation drower for me is the best choice, for the point 2 I dont know what the main screen show to the user and because of that i dont know if you can use navigation drower with activities or not.

Comment: What harm does it do to have this question be answerable? Any decent answer would qualify that it's not the only possible one, and if didn't still no one would follow it blindly. Feels like you guys just want something to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [navigation drawer design pattern](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html). It can be realized using [navigation view](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html?m=1) or [list view](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

But, yes it is all about fragments, because if you have the same-priority components, you should keep navigation style between them still the same, so if you do it with activities you must have the similar navigation drawers in three different activities, and it is bad, believe me.